# Index simplification help

Tags: logarithms

How is $3^{5/12}\cdot6^{1/3}$ simplified to $3^{3/4}\cdot 2^{1/3}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Use the fact that $6=2·3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3^{5/12}6^{1/3}=3^{5/12}2^{1/3}3^{1/3}=2^{1/3}3^{3/4}$, using the index laws $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ and $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$